# Plot quantiles of distribution in ggplot2 with facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, quantile, density-plot

I'm currently plotting a number of different distributions of first differences from a number of regression models in ggplot. To facilitate interpretation of the differences, I want to mark the 2.5% and the 97.5% percentile of each distribution. Since I will be doing quite a few plots, and because the data is grouped in two dimension (model and type), I would like to define and plot the respective percentiles in the ggplot environment. Plotting the distributions using facets gets me to exactly where I want except for the percentiles. I could of course do this more manually, but I would ideally want to find a solution where I am still able to use `facet_grid`, since this spared me a lot of hassle trying to fit the different plots together.

Here's an example using simulated data:

```
df.example <- data.frame(model = rep(c("a", "b"), length.out = 500), 
                      type = rep(c("t1", "t2", "t2", "t1"), 
                      length.outh = 250), value = rnorm(1000))

 ggplot(df.example, aes(x = value)) +
 facet_grid(type ~ model) +
 geom_density(aes(fill = model, colour = model))
```

I've tried to add quantiles in two ways. The first one produces an error message:

```
 ggplot(df.example, aes(x = value)) +
 facet_grid(. ~ model) +
 geom_density(aes(fill = model, colour = model)) +
 geom_vline(aes(x = value), xintercept = quantile(value, probs = c(.025, .975)))
```

> ```
> Error in quantile(value, probs = c(0.025, 0.975)) : object 'value' not found
> ```

While the second one gets me the quantiles for the the complete variable and not for the sub-densities. That is, the plotted quantiles are identical for all four densities.

```
 ggplot(df.example, aes(x = value)) +
 facet_grid(type ~ model) +
 geom_density(aes(fill = model, colour = model)) +
 geom_vline(xintercept = quantile(df.example$value, probs = c(.025, .975)))
```

I consequently wonder if there is a way to plot the specific quantiles for each subgroup within the ggplot2 environment?

Greatly appreciate any input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can calculate the quantiles beforehand.

Using your example data:

```
library (dplyr)
d2 <- df.example %>%
  group_by(model, type) %>%
  summarize(lower = quantile(value, probs = .025),
            upper = quantile(value, probs = .975))
```

And then plot like this:

```
ggplot(df.example, aes(x = value)) +
  facet_grid(type ~ model) +
  geom_density(aes(fill = model, colour = model)) +
  geom_vline(data = d2, aes(xintercept = lower)) +
  geom_vline(data = d2, aes(xintercept = upper))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Use plyr (or dplyr, data.table) to precompute these values ...

```
set.seed(1)
# ...

df.q <- ddply(df.example, .(model, type),
              summarize, q=quantile(value, c(.025, .975)))    
p + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=q), data=df.q)
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays, it’s possible to use `stat_summary()` with the `orientation` option
to achieve the same result without precomputation.

Define a dummy `y` value for each panel to group the observations along with
`orientation = "y"`. Then use a custom `fun` to compute a vector of
desired quantiles for each panel in `stat_summary()`. To display the result
as vertical lines, specify `geom = "vline"` and its required `xintercept`
from the computed `x` values with `xintercept = after_stat(x)` in the aesthetic
specification, now using the result computed with `fun`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)

df.example <- data.frame(
  model = rep(c("a", "b"), length.out = 500),
  type = rep(c("t1", "t2", "t2", "t1"),
    length.outh = 250
  ), value = rnorm(1000)
)

ggplot(df.example, aes(x = value)) +
  facet_grid(type ~ model) +
  geom_density(aes(fill = model, colour = model)) +
  stat_summary(
    geom = "vline",
    orientation = "y",
    # y is a required aesthetic, so use a dummy value
    aes(y = 1, xintercept = after_stat(x)),
    fun = function(x) {
      quantile(x, probs = c(0.025, 0.975))
    }
  )
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) If you use `fun` instead of `fun.data`, you can make this slightly simpler: `stat_summary(aes(y = 1, xintercept = after_stat(x)), fun = function(x) quantile(x, probs = c(0.025, 0.975)), geom = "vline", orientation = "y")`

Comment: Or `stat_summary(aes(y = 1, xintercept = after_stat(x)), fun = quantile, fun.args = list(probs = c(0.025, 0.975)), geom = "vline", orientation = "y")`.

Comment: @Axeman aah yeah thanks for pointing that out. That would be simpler. Another way that comes to mind now would be to keep `fun.data` but change the data frame to have a column called `yintercept` and drop the `xintercept = stat(x)` from the `aes()` altogether.

Comment: That said, I think the `fun` approach is definitely easier to actually remember. I've edited it in, favouring the anonymous function still as I find it more readable, personally. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Good question. The more general version of the same question is: how do you call functions on the subsetted datasets when using facets? This seems like a very useful feature and so I searched around but could not find anything about it.

The answers already given are excellent. Another option is to use [`multiplot()`](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_%28ggplot2%29/) as a way of doing the faceting manually.

Comment: I agree. Both solutions are very neat, but, as you note, does not really solve the issue I adress in my question. This would indeed by a very interesting feature for ggplot.